# Cross platform vector interface in C

Tags: c

C does not have built-in vector types, but many common compilers and processors have their own vector intrinsics. MacOS has a built-in SIMD library which simply creates `typedef` vector types to GCC vector extension types. However this does not exist on Linux or on compilers other than GCC. Also on Intel there is supposed to be `<immintrin.h>` but that only works on Intel processors.

Is there a simple cross platform interface that maps portable items to appropriate vector types? I just need a simple `float`/`double`/`int` vector with 3 values that can be added/subtracted from each other.

I want to not have to rely on the compiler to auto-vectorize my code.